# JAVA - How to map efficiently a property from a list to an other?

Tags: java, java-stream

So i have those two object

```
public class Setting {

@Id
private Long fooId;

@Transient
private String fooLabel

//GETTER and SETTER ommited
}
```

and

```
public class Foo {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column
private String fooLabelEn

@Column
private String fooLabelFr

public getLocalLabel(){}
}
```

I can easily get the label i need, in english or in an other language, and i want to add it in my list of Setting. I can't modify the Foo table, and i can't save all label in Setting.

I tried something like this, but it's not really efficent.

```
fooList = fooRepository.findAllById(settingIdList);
settingList.stream()
    .map(setting -> setting.setLabel(fooList.stream()
        .filter(foo -> foo.getId().equals(setting.getFooId())
        .findFirst()
        .get()
        .getLocalLabel)
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think i forgot something, and i feel i don't go in the right direction. I can only save ids for the settings, so i have to do something like this.

Does anyone have a complient solution ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's unclear if it works, just slow, or doesn't work. If it's just slow, consider putting `fooList` into a `Map<Long,Foo>` for efficient lookup instead of that inner stream+filter magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help explain better what @tevemadar suggested, since you have been able to retrieve fooList from the data source, you can go extra mile by turning the result to a map, as follows:

```
Map<Long, Foo> fooMap = fooRepository.findAllById(settingIdList).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, foo -> foo))
```

So you can now do the following:

```
settingList.stream()
    .peek(setting -> setting.setLabel(fooMap.get(setting.getFooId()).getLocalLabel()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

One can argue this may not be entirely null safe, suppose you cannot find `setting.getFooId()` in `fooMap`. Something you can do is:

```
settingList.stream()
    .peek(setting -> setting.setLabel(fooMap.getOrDefault(setting.getFooId(), new Foo(-1)).getLocalLabel()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `new Foo(-1)` creates a naive instance of `foo` with it's `localLabel` set to `-1`. It totally now depends on your implementation, you may not want this.

Comment: I have used `peek` instead of `map` since you don't really do a transformation which is what `map` does, you are just altering a field in the `settingList`, so `peek` is more logical and recommended.

Comment: Thank you, it's works perfectly with `peek`. I'm not used to this method in Java Stream but it's the perfect one for my needs !